# How to make scrollable long image page?

Tags: java, android

I am making activity showing TOS(Terms of Service) contents. 
TOS text content is written very long single image, which should be scrolled. And confirm button is located below it.
Is there any best practice to make it?

I used `ScrollView` to scroll contents.
`ScrollView` contains `ImageView` and `ImageButton`.

First, I insert very long TOS content image by `android:src` attribute.
But, xxxhdpi image file is about 1MB size and height is about 18000 thus the app crashed (it shows 'canvas trying to draw too large bitmap' error)

After that, I try using image library which are `Glide` and `Picasso`. Using them, the error doesn't occur but image quality got degraded.
I searched and tried many solution to keep resolution and render speed but failed.

I think trying to use smaller image is better solution, but in emulator scroll speed and behavior was very strange when used src attribute to draw image.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                some code... />

        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I am not sure if using single long image with `scrollView` to show TOS contents is correct or not. And not sure if it is possible to handle long image properly with `ImageView`.

Comment: Why would you use something like Image to show TOS? Why not just add it inside TextView so it could be shown properly across all the devices?

Comment: Agreed, why use an image instead of just text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respectfully, you're making life difficult for yourself.

Having the TOS in image form only is unusual; the 'correct' approach is to have your TOS in text form, which would also be fastest to code.

If the TOS is composed elsewhere, and you don't wish to re-type it, then possibly feed the image to an online OCR service and see what comes back?

Alternately, use a WebView component connecting to a web server serving a page with only the TOS image. (But this is a bad idea, because now you'll need to set-up and maintain a web-server!)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Android development is not my major work so I have little knowledge about it. I thought using single image within scrollview would be straightforward. Now I am trying to use textview to show TOS contents and searching way of keep styling of it as possible (Font size, line spacing etc). Could you give me any advice?

Comment: Suggestion: you should be able to specify that the textview will display HTML; use that for the mark-up, then provide the required formatting that way. I hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put image to `drawable-nodpi` folder

If you are using Glide try to use `.thumbnail()` attr

Add to Android manifest `largeHeap` attr

And at least decrease size of big image